# Several virtualNetworkRules in Storage account ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to allow/add several subnets to the storage account "selected vnet" part using an array parameter and the copy function but get the error:

"**Status Message: Values for request parameters are invalid: networkAcls.virtualNetworkRules[*].id.** "

Relevant part in Storage account deploy template file:

```
        "networkAcls": {
        "bypass": "AzureServices",
        "copy": [
            {
                "name": "virtualNetworkRules",
                "count": "[length(parameters('selectedvnetaccess'))]",
                "input": {
                    "id": "[parameters('selectedvnetaccess')[copyIndex('virtualNetworkRules')].id]",
                    "action": "[parameters('selectedvnetaccess')[copyIndex('virtualNetworkRules')].action]"
            }
            }
               ]
          },
```

Array parameter in parameter file

```
"selectedvnetaccess": {
            "value": [
                {
                "id": "/subscriptions/bxxxxxa-5e2d-4ba2-94c9-7852e933b930/resourceGroups/RG-xxxxx0000-TEST-INFRA-DEPLOY/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/testvnet001",
                "action": "allow"
                }
            ]
```